# Any idea what parts were replaced on my water softener?

Tags: water-softener

I bought a Hague WaterMax 63BAQ used water softener about two years ago. I had a local plumber offer to install it in exchange for some computer work. Once it was installed for a day, it started making a clicking noise and the digital display would say 'Home Not Found'. I unplugged it and let it sit for a few years.

I'm not questioning the diagnosis - just very curious as to what parts it looks like were replaced. Does anyone know what these are?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears to be the Brine Valve Housing and the Drive Gear, looking at the manual.

[Hague WaterMax 60 Series Owners Manual - Hague Quality Water](http://www.haguewater.com/pdf/Hague%20WaterMax%2060%20Series%20Owners%20Manual.pdf)  -- Page 34, parts 4 and 11